# Как сделать запись в БД после закрытия браузера?

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Мне нужно добавить тайм-аут юзера DB после закрытия браузера

Comment: js тайм-аут вызывающий периодически скрипт отмечающий таймштап вызова, и дальше отбирать последние записи не подходит?

Comment: Можно подробнее? Опрашивать аяксом что? Не знаете, может в HTML5 чего подобного есть?

Comment: ajax'ом отправлять вызов страницы (site.com/timstamp.php + post id_user&uniq_key), к примеру с индентификатором пользователя+уникальный ключ содержащийся в сессии(что бы подделать не могли).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В JS можно использовать  [onBeforeUnload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload) И поймать событие закрытия браузера с меткой времени.

Comment: А вы уверены, что это событие сработает тогда когда это надо? А если браузер отвалился? Или сеть пропала?

Я сомневаюсь, что ТС интересует сам факт закрытия браузера, его скорее интересует окончание работы с сайтом. А здесь как раз хорошо сработает оповещалка о том, что пользователь онлайн и никуда не ушел. Перестал слать запросы - значит пользователь ушел.

Comment: Конечно, если сеть пропала, такой вариант не сработает, очевидно, просто в вопросе было конкретно сказано "после закрытия браузера", я привел событие, возникающее в браузере при "закрытии", вот и все. Дальше уже пускай ТС выбирает.